# Send array to php file using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I'm trying to send an array to php file using ajax, but I'm not able to get it in the php file, this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
            url: 'alerts_result_ajax.php',
            data: {'alerts': JSON.stringify(data)},
            success: function(res) {
                   $(".alerts_result").html(res);
                    }
                });
```

The variable data is an array, and I'm sure of it, in alerts_result_ajax.php file, I have this code

```
   $alerts=json_decode($_POST['alerts']);
   echo count($alerts);
```

It prints 0, but the array is not 0 size, what's wrong?

Comment: Where you are defining the array `data` ?

Comment: Stop being sure, and look at the data actually being sent in the request using the Net tab of your browser's developer tools. Then quote it in your question.

Comment: The data came from another ajax, I print it before send it to the next ajax, its size is 5

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['alerts']);` then think

Comment: I think you serialize the array in a faulty way. You could try passing data as an object to jQuery. It should take care of properly serializing the data. Also for debugging, not just echo the count, but also the array itself...

Comment: @JavaJens — No. That's a perfectly OK way to serialise the data.

Comment: Make absolutely sure what is arriving at PHP, So do a `print_r($_POST)` then you can be absolutely sure what is being received by your script.

Comment: The problem is solved, it was dummy mistake!! the php array was not received correctly, thank

Answer (score 0):

it looks pretty damn bad to name your array(data) the same name as the ajax field...

`data: {'alerts': JSON.stringify(data)}`      (notice the name data appears twice hear, this could cause a lot of issues that are hard to track).

Comment: Usually it doesn't really causes any problem, since one is a property/parameter and the other a variable.

Comment: That's not the problem

Comment: Usually it doesn't really causes any problem - but it is really bad programming. just the name 'data' is a very bad name for a variable regardless of having two of them...